# How do you Merge 2 Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2], index=['A', 'B'])

s2 = pd.Series([3, 4], index=['C', 'D'])
```

I want to combine `s1` and `s2` to create `s3` which is:

```
s3 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

NB: There is no index overlap

Comment: in this case you can `concat`: `pd.concat([s1,s2])` but are you after a real `merge`? like `s1.to_frame().merge(s2.to_frame(), how='outer')`? the problem here is that the series won't have a column name unless you add one

Comment: What do you mean by real merge?

Comment: No just looking to make 1 big series combining the 2.

Comment: A real merge as in merging index and/or column values

Comment: There is no overlap in index. You can just ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from @EdChum works well, but numpy stacking is faster when you don't need to worry about index alignment.

```
In [18]: pd.DataFrame( np.hstack((s1.values, s2.values))  , index=np.hstack((s1.index.values, s2.index.values)))
Out[18]: 
   0
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4

In [19]: %timeit pd.concat([s1, s2])

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.31 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit pd.DataFrame( np.hstack((s1.values, s2.values)  ), index=np.hstack((s1.index.values, s2.index.values)))

10000 loops, best of 3: 214 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`concat()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), it automatically executes an outer join:

```
pd.concat([s1, s2])
```

result:

```
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: According to the documentation, this is also more efficient for multiple series in comparision to append:
"Iteratively appending to a Series can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append values to a list and then concatenate the list with the original Series all at once."

Answer (score 1):

If there is no index overlap, you could just use the append function  defined for series with the default values

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.append.html#pandas.Series.append

```
s1.append(s2)
```

should return:

```
A    1
B    2
C    3
D    4
dtype: int64
```